# How to make an image and text popup after clicking on a word? Html, css and js

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, popup

I have this list:

```
<nav>
  Navigation Bar
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">
        Myself
        <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">My description </span>
        <img src="/images/picture.jpg" alt="My picture" />
      </div>

      <script>
        function myFunction() {
          var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
          popup.classList.toggle("show");
        }
      </script>
    </li>
    <li>Contact</li>
    <li>Other</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I want that when I clic on `Myself`, my description popups with my image. But it doesn't work.

Can you help me please, what I'm I doing wrong?

I need to use html, css and js.

Thanks!!!

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_popup.asp

Comment: Maybe you are missing the `.show` class please take a look to this example https://jsfiddle.net/m7vr6xyu/

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you are missing some CSS rules.

Let's have a look on this line:

```js
popup.classList.toggle("show");
```

The `toggle` function here will add a class `show` class if the element `popup` does not have one, otherwise remove it.

That means the item with class `popuptext` should **not** display by default and unless the `show` class is added.

Therefore, you should define 2 CSS styles like the following:

```css
.popuptext.show {
  display: inline-block; // show element when you have the class name 'show'
}
.popuptext {
  display: none; // hide by default
}
```

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/3bmqdcsg/

Comment: Ohhhh! Ok yes thanks! But how do I make the image popup with the description?

Comment: Put the description together with the img element inside the .popuptext div.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your CSS code for `.show`, I can't really determine what went wrong, but adding some CSS code for `.show` and `.popuptext`, everything works!

**EDIT: I have also added a simple animation code to animate a "popup"**

```css
.show {
  display: block!important;
  /* The bottom is for animation when the popup gets shown */
  animation: popup .2s 1;
}

@keyframes popup {
  from { transform: scale(0); }
  to { transform: scale(1); }
}


.popuptext {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  Navigation Bar
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">
        Myself
        <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">My description</span>
        <img src="/images/picture.jpg" alt="My picture" />
      </div>

      <script>
        function myFunction() {
          var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
          popup.classList.toggle("show");
        }
      </script>
    </li>
    <li>Contact</li>
    <li>Other</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Ohhhh! Ok yes thanks! But how do I make the image popup with the description?

Comment: What do you mean by popup? The simple way is to add an animation. I will now edit my answer

Comment: I have added a simple animation!